# Webflux repeat method has strange behaviors with different operators

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Repeat operator could make stream re-subscribe, and I found some behaviors in different situations.

example code as below:

```java
Mono.just(5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 1: " + i))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 2: " + i))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 3: " + i))
        .repeat(2)
        .subscribe();
```

output:

```
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
```

it's certainly right. then I change the repeat position.

```java
Mono.just(5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 1: " + i))
        .repeat(2)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 2: " + i))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 3: " + i))
        .subscribe();
```

output is the same as before.

```
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: 5
```

So I think it **cannot affect origin streams' execution order.**

when I add then operator into streams.

```java
Mono.just(5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 1: " + i))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 2: " + i))
        .then(Mono.just("hello"))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 3: " + i))
        .repeat(2)
        .subscribe();
```

output:

```
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: hello
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: hello
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: hello
```

It looks like re-subscribed all streams, and I change the position again.

```java
Mono.just(5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 1: " + i))
        .repeat(2)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 2: " + i))
        .then(Mono.just("hello"))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 3: " + i))
        .subscribe();
```

output:

```
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 1: 5
next 2: 5
next 3: hello
```

It's certainly **could affect streams' execution order**.

Then I'm confused a lot, what situation it will be affected or not?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call `then` operator on a `Flux` it will be executed exactly once **after** the `Flux` **completed** including repeats. It doesn't care about how many elements there were before it. That's why you see only a single `hello` in the last example. Added comments at the end of the line to see the switch between the two types.

```java
Mono.just(5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 1: " + i)) // mono
        .repeat(2) // flux
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 2: " + i))  // flux
        .then(Mono.just("hello")) // mono  (triggered after previous Flux completed)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("next 3: " + i)) // mono 
        .subscribe();
```

If the `then` operator comes before `repeat`, then it will be repeated like everything else

Comment: Thanks. It looks clear and help me a lot. I wonder why `doOnNext` wasn't affected by `repeat` in my second example code.because it is a non-side-effects consumer? could I understand that `repeat` executed when the streams were switched at the first time.
`doOnNext` won't switch the streams, but `then` will.